# About Open GL and Augmented reality

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, augmented-reality

i have final project about AR based location.
but it's stuck in located object 3D to real camera.

how i can put 3D object to real camera like pokemon GO but have perspective too like open GL. can i implement openGL ES to real camera. if can how to implement coordinate with GPS? 
help please

Comment: Stack overflow is not a coding service, and this type of question is far too high level to have a short answer.

Comment: Please use the tag `augmented-reality` instead of `ar`. `ar` stands for _the Unix archiver utility, used primarily for maintaining static libraries._ on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to parse your 3D model content.

For example, if you use .obj file as a 3D model, you should parse it firstly. Then you should use *glNormal3f(x, y, z)* and *glTexCoord2d(x, y)* and *glVertex3f(x, y, z)* for rendering 3D model.

You can find .obj parser on the [official OpenGL tutorial web page](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/).